# Triggering GAS function via URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, arduino

Very new to this, but giving it a shot. I am trying to set up an Arduino motion sensor to trigger a script. At this point, my goal is to trigger a script via URL. I found this code below that I am working through, but I continue to get this error when running/debugging.

> TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined. (line 4, file "Code")

I have been looking into `e.parameter` object, but have not been able to make any headway

```
      function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(e)
  var passedString,whatToReturn;

  passedString = e.parameter.searchStringName;
  if (passedString === 'tylog') {
    whatToReturn = tylog();  //Run function One
  };

 return ContentService.createTextOutput(whatToReturn);
};


var mns = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Monster")
var tyl = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("tyLog")
var tyd = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("tyData")
var twl = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("twLog")
var twd = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("twData")
var tym = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("tyMaster")
var twm = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("twMaster")
var test = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test")
var tydate = tyd.getRange('A2');
var tydur = tyd.getRange(2, 2);

// Start functions
function start() {
  tyl.getRange('A1').setValue(new Date());
  twl.getRange('A1').setValue(new Date());
}

//Log Typhoon ride
function tylog() {
  tyl.getRange(tyl.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(new Date());  
}

//Log Twister ride
function twlog() {
  twl.getRange(twl.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(new Date());
}


//Send Data to both logs and clear

function tyclear() {
  tyd.getRange('A2:H2').copyTo(tym.getRange(tym.getLastRow() + 1, 1), {contentsOnly: true});
  twd.getRange('A2:H2').copyTo(twm.getRange(twm.getLastRow() + 1, 1), {contentsOnly: true});
  tyl.getRange('A1:A100').clearContent();
  twl.getRange('A1:A100').clearContent();

}
```

URL Request:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxC5zYevR1IhfFcUMjmIqUaQ1dKNHTm4mhmWBq_Rc9HgemJQ6Q/exec?searchStringName=tylog
```

[image: Debug Image]

I put this into a new project by itself and it still returned `undefined`​.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var passedString,whatToReturn;

  passedString = e.parameter.searchStringName;
  if (passedString === 'functionOne') {
    whatToReturn = functionOne();  //Run function One
  };

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(whatToReturn);
};

function functionOne() {
  var something;
return ContentService.createTextOutput("Hello, world!"); }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194573/discussion-on-question-by-brannan-holland-triggering-gas-function-via-url).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your URL should be `https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxC5zYevR1IhfFcUMjmIqUaQ1dKNHTm4mhmWBq_Rc9HgemJQ6Q/exec?searchStringName=functionOne`

After pondering this question for a while it makes no sense to require a return from functionOne.  I was getting the client server communication mixed up with the Get request process.  For most Get requests the request suggests some type of response since in general we're looking for some type of content to be displayed.  In this situation that may not be required since the requestor is a machine.

The use of `e.parameter.paramname;` just enables us to send key/value pairs from within our querystring that we can recover to redirect our server actions.

Comment: @BrannanHolland - are you sure it is still not working? Cooper is right, I overlooked the fact that `tylog()` function does not return anything and thus passes `undefined` to `ContentService`

Comment: I see. Since `tylog()` just makes changes to the sheet it is returning `undefined`? However, the function is still not executing on the sheet. Should I try removing the `return` portion of the script?

Comment: In a manner of speaking, yes. Your `tylog()` should make changes as is, though (assuming you pass the query with your get request since your `tylog()` run depends on query parameter being present).

Comment: I removed `passedString = e.parameter.searchStringName;` and now its working, but im still getting undefined. I understand why its undefined now, but any thoughts why removing that fixed it?

Comment: @BrannanHolland - if you removed it and the `if` statement (=made `tylog()` execution unconditional), then, assuming you simply called `/exec` with no query, the `tylog()` never fired due to failed check `undefined==='tylog'`.

Comment: Im quite lost again. I removed just about all the code that had to do with triggering it via a URL and its still working. Unsure whats going on now...

Comment: @BrannanHolland - from your new question and the comment I assume you still experience issues with calling specific functions via query string? *P.s. Btw, when you post a comment to another person's answer, if others aren't mentioned via @, they won't be notified.* Cooper, I think your original answer was exactly on point - from the extended discussion I noticed that the problem Brannan had wasn't the `TypeError`, but the `whatToReturn` being `undefined` due to `tylog()` not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

**2020 UPD:**

Upon revisiting the question, I noticed that the OP runs the `doGet` trigger in the context of *script editor*, hence the `e` becoming undefined (as it is only constructed when a request hits the URL with an HTTP request with `GET` method).

Thus, the answer to the *debugging* part is:

> When running a trigger manually from the script editor, event object will be *unavailable*

The answer to the *running* part is as a result of an extended discussion:

> When assigning a result of the function, one has to put the `return` statement inside the function, and the `tylog` function did not return anything.

Also note that any change to a Web App code, unless accessing it via `/dev` endpoint (i.e. via `/exec` endpoint), won't be available until *after redeployment*.

**References**

1. Web Apps [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: Updated my code up top to reflect what I have now. I am still experiencing 'undefined'